# MS ACCESS: Update table record from 2 values in form

Tags: ms-access

I have 4 tables

1. table 1 - clubid, Club
2. table 2 - temaid, Team
3. table 3 - teamclubid, clubid, teamid
4. table 4 - playerid, last name, name, teamclubid

I want to create a form in which the user selects from 2 different dropdowns: the club and the team, and when the record is updated, table 4 should be updated with the teamclubID.

Can any anyone let me know how can this be done or where to look for information on how to achieve it?

Thanks,

Comment: Should **temaid** be **teamid**?

Comment: yes it should be teamid

Comment: The form you are creating, which table is the data source?

Answer (score 0):

Could use DLookup() domain aggregate function to lookup teamclubid using clubid and teamid as criteria and VBA to populate field.

```vb
Me!teamclubid = DLookup("teamclubid", "[table 3]", "clubid = " &
    Me.cbxClub & " AND teamid = " & Me.cbxTeam)
```

The trick is figuring out what event to put code into - possibly form BeforeUpdate.

I presume a team can belong to only one club. An alternative is to eliminate table3 and put clubid as foreign key in Table2. Then just save teamid into Table4. Its associated club info can always be retrieved by joining tables in query.

Advise not to use exact same field name in multiple tables.

Comment: thanks for the update. There are multiple clubs, with multiple teams. All the clubs have same organization. Club1, team1, team2,team3. A player can only be pertaining to 1 club and team per season

Comment: Doesn't change my comments. Each team would have a unique identifier in table2.

Comment: Perhaps is my lack of understanding on rdbs but  isn’t it table 3 an auxiliar table for a many to many relantionship? One club can have many teams, but at the same time Team A is present in many clubs.

Comment: Okay, then my presumption was not correct and your arrangement is appropriate, if it really is the same Team A - same team name, same team members - but seems odd to me. A team is paying to participate in multiple clubs? Even so still seems like each team is an independent entity with its own standings in each club it joins, regardless that the team members are the same people.

Comment: The idea is different clubs. However all clubs are organized the same. Team A, Team B, Team C. One player can only belong to one team at a time per season

Comment: Okay, back to my suggestion each team is unique and could just save its ID into table 4.